# Create subsite in SharePoint 2013 programmatically

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I have a trouble with searching information "How create subsite in Sharepoint 2013 with JS programmatically". Can someone give me a link on guide or answer on my question? I use sharepoint-hosted app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you google it?

You can check below links
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88483/how-do-we-create-sub-site-using-javascript-object-module

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/98769/create-site-collection-from-rest-api

http://sympmarc.com/2014/03/30/create-a-subsite-in-sharepoint-2013-using-rest-calls/

http://sharepointryan.com/2013/09/10/create-a-sharepoint-site-spweb-using-rest-in-spd-2013-workflow/

Comment: Thank you. Yes, i was google it, but all variants which i got were on C#.